# Are scalar and vector fields basically just "multi-valued" functions?

Tags: notation, terminology, vector-fields

Not really familiar with terminology in higher Mathematics, so I will try to use python to express my ideas instead.

> **From Wikipedia:** a scalar field associates a scalar value to every point in a space

So basically this is just a function that returns a single value then?

```
# a scalar field in one dimensional space
def scalar_field(x):
    return x * 2

# a scalar field in two dimensional space
def scalar_field(x,y):
    return x * y * 2
```

> **From Wikipedia:** a vector field associates a vector to every point in space

So basically this is just a function that returns multiple values then?

```
# a vector field in one dimensional space
def vector_field(x):
    return (x*2, x*2)

# a vector field in two dimensional space
def vector_field(x,y):
    return (x*y*2, x*y*2)
```

Is this all there is to this concept, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222768/why-are-vector-valued-functions-well-defined-when-multivalued-functions-arent

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The notation merely stresses that the space may be high dimensional.

Comment: It is good though to avoid the phrase "multivalued function" though, which is usually used to suggest that you don't know which of the values will be returned.

Comment: Your third example does not constitute a vector field on ${\mathbb R}^1$ but the parametric representation of a curve in ${\mathbb R}^2$. – The vectors of a vector field have the  "dimension" of the base space.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter could you follow up with your post? maybe a code example as well? as I have said I am new to mathematics and many of these more abstract terms confuse me greatly w/o examples